# PHP MYSQL UPDATE if Exist or INSERT if not?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert, on-duplicate-key

I have no idea if this is even remotely correct. I have a class where I would like to update the database if the fields currently exist or insert if they do not. The complication is that I am doing a joining 3 tables (set_colors, school_art, baseimage)

Any help would be really great.

Here is what I have:

```
public function set_layer_colors($value) {
    global $db;

    $result_array = mysql_query("
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM set_colors WHERE school_art_id = '{$value}')

      UPDATE set_colors (school_art_id, baseimage_id, sub_folder, layer)
        SELECT school_art.id, baseimage.id, baseimage.sub_folder, baseimage.layer
        FROM school_art 
        JOIN baseimage ON baseimage.base_folder = school_art.series_code 
        WHERE baseimage.image_type = 'B' ORDER BY school_art.id 

    ELSE

     INSERT INTO set_colors (school_art_id, baseimage_id, sub_folder, layer)
        SELECT school_art.id, baseimage.id, baseimage.sub_folder, baseimage.layer
        FROM school_art 
        JOIN baseimage ON baseimage.base_folder = school_art.series_code 
        WHERE baseimage.image_type = 'B' ORDER BY school_art.id 
        ");

    return $result_array;
}
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the following syntax:

```
INSERT INTO <table> (field1, field2, field3, ...) 
VALUES ('value1', 'value2','value3', ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
field1='value1', field2='value2', field3='value3', ...
```

> **Note:** With `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, the affected-rows value per row is `1` if the row is *inserted* as a new row, `2` if an existing row is *updated*, and `0` if an existing row is *set to its current values*.

MySQL Documentation: [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: To be more correct you don't need indication of Primary keys. So if  field1 is a key then

......
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
field2='value2', field3='value3', ... (starting with field2)

Comment: just remember to give the target column the UNIQUE constraint

Comment: @StefanoZanetti, your field names do not match: `psw` vs `password`. Further, you have not specified the `role` field in the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause (I am not sure if this matters).

Answer (score 34):

Two choices:

[MySQL Manual :: INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

or

[MySQL Manual :: REPLACE INTO Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Both will allow you to do the insert-if-not-exists-or-update in one query.

Comment: Thanks, REPLACE INTO is much better for my case otherwise I'd have to call "$query->send_long_data(1, $buff)" twice, one for the INSERT and one for the UPDATE

Comment: Nooo... If we are using "REPLACE INTO ", the other FOREIGN KEY related table's data would be deleted if the PRIMARY data is exist.

Comment: Heads-up about `REPLACE` -- it implicitly deletes the entry it tries update and adds a new one, thus if you have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` key, such as `ID`, it will be auto-incremented too!