# How to rewrite the same mysql table row if the item already exists?

Tags: php, mysql, magento, csv

Basically, I wanna go through the entire table from top to bottom. If the item already exists, update the row with new data. If not, append the data to the table. How do I go about implementing this? Thank you

Update: That would be simple in raw query, however, Im using it on a MVC architecture.

Comment: Seems like a dup of:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853190/php-mysql-update-if-exist-or-insert-if-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i can suggest to use magento inbuilt function `insertOnDuplicate`

```
 $bind = array(
           'product_link_attribute_id' => $attributeInfo['id'],
           'link_id'                   => $linkId,
           'value'                     => $value
              );

$adapter->insertOnDuplicate($attributeTable, $bind, array('value'));
```

where `$bind` is the array or row value you want to insert and third argument in function should be `array('value')` and this would be list of column you want to check if value is already exist in table with same value.

Also you can find implementaion of this method in below file

```
lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: $adapter = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write'); so something like that would allow me to loop through the database table and insert only if it's a duplicate? well, how does it determine that's a duplicate column? I want to check if Sku column already has the same value then overwrite the entire row with new data

Comment: yes you can add this as describe in my answer as `array('value')` change it to `array('sku')` so if you have already exist sku then it will update row as per your data.

Comment: Any idea how I could truncate a database table for a module?

Comment: you can use this   `$this->_db->query('TRUNCATE '. $this->_table);` where `$this->_db` your DB  connection object.
It would be glad for me if u will vote up my ans so some one can use in future

Comment: thats exactly what I ended up using. I could also loop through the collection and delete each item however it will not reset auto increment like truncate would.

Comment: is this helpful to you ? to achieve your solution ?

Comment: oh yea thats perfect. ive been using truncate. thank you

Answer (score 0):

the [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) command will delete the row if the key exists, and insert the same info afterwards.

This means that any auto incremental key will be changed after performing the operation because it's not the same row. It's a new one with the exact info from the previosly deleted row.

Answer (score -1):

Please check this code :

```
function sendtodb($data) {
    $invoiceid = $data['invoiceid'];
    if($invoiceid != "") {
        $checkinvoice = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `paypal_ajustment_data_pure` WHERE `InvoiceID`='$invoiceid'") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($checkinvoice) > 0) {
            $paypalreferenceid = $data['paypalreferenceid'];
            $checkpreferenceid =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `paypal_ajustment_data_pure` WHERE `InvoiceID`='$invoiceid' AND `PayPalReferenceID`='$paypalreferenceid'") or die(mysql_error());  
            if(mysql_num_rows($checkpreferenceid) == 0)
                $updatereferncceid = mysql_query("UPDATE `paypal_ajustment_data_pure` SET `PayPalReferenceID`='$paypalreferenceid' WHERE `InvoiceID`='$invoiceid'") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        else {
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `nume_mage`.`paypal_ajustment_data_pure` (`id`, `TransactionID`, `InvoiceID`, `PayPalReferenceID`, `TransactionInitiationDate`, `TransactionCompletionDate`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, '$data[TransactionID]', '$data[invoiceid]', '$data[paypalreferenceid]', '$data[transactionintiationdate]', '$data[transactioncompletedate]', '1')") or die(mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_query("update `paypal_ajustment_data` set status=2 where id= '$data[id]'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
    else {
        mysql_query("update `paypal_ajustment_data` set status=3 where id= '$data[id]'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is not for you but this is just to understand logic.. i can show logic so you can understand for code let me know your table name