# Can I get INSERT/UPDATE id with single request?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, lastinsertid

I have the following code:

```
$put_tag_rq = $DBH->prepare( "
  INSERT INTO `tags`
  SET
    `name` = :name
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `id` = `id`
" );
$put_tag_rq->execute( array(
  'name' => $tag,
) );
$tag_id = $DBH->lastInsertId();
echo "***********Last insert ID = $tag_id<br>";
```

Please note that the `name` is also the tab's key.

This code works fine if the inserting `name` tag is not yet presented in the table. But lastInsertId() returns 0 if `name` already there.

Of course I could do two requests: first to check if the `name` tag already presented in the tab (and obtain its ID) and the second to insert the `name` is already presented in the tab.

But I think that it should be simpler. Isn't it?

Comment: What are you trying to update? You have set the `id` to its existing value, so MySQL won't modify the row at all.  The value of `affectedRows()` would differ, 1 if a new insertion made, 2 if an existing row modified, 0 if no change made.

Comment: Or is it that you want to _return the `id`_ of the updated row?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I've updated the question that `name` is also the key, so in case `name` already exist - UPDATE statement should work.

Comment: I understand that `name` is the unique index, but what is the purpose of `id = id`? You are not making a change.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski that's right: if the `name` already in the tab SQL request shouldn't make any change. I'd leave ON DUPLICATE KEY clause empty but it's not allowed by the MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the MySQL that you're looking for:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

And more info on how to do it in php:
[PHP MYSQL UPDATE if Exist or INSERT if not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853190/php-mysql-update-if-exist-or-insert-if-not)

Comment: Thanks! I should use `id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` syntax.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!