# PHP MySQL Not Updating DB

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

I am having what seems like a syntax issue, but I am getting zero errors.
First off, I tested each variable to make sure they were being properly populated by the form, so there is no issue there.  When "$RespondentOrPetitioner" is marked with "r" or "p" it should be adding the data to my MySQL database using this:

```
if ($RespondentOrPetitioner == "p") {
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO alkouric_darling.customer(CaseNumber, PetitionerFirstName, PetitionerLastName, RespondentFirstName, RespondentLastName, RespondentAttorneyFullName, PetitionerAttorneyFullName )
      VALUES ('$CaseNumber','$PetitionerFirstName', '$PetitionerLastName', '$RespondentFirstName', '$RespondentLastName','$RespondentAttorneyFullName','$AttorneyFullName')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

However, this is not updating the DB for these fields "RespondentFirstName, RespondentLastName, PetitionerFirstName, PetitionerLastName, PetitionerAttorneyFullName," and "RespondentAttorneyFullName."

I tried copying/pasting just the small $sql statement into a separate file and it worked just fine, so why will it not work on my document?  Every other MYSQL code works in this document, but the 2 that are inside the "IF" statements do not.  I've spent hours trying to figure this out and ran it through multiple PHP syntax checkers and I still can't figure this out, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the whole code:

```
<?php
$servername = "99.99.99.99";
$username = "darling";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "alkouric_darling";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// enter San Bernardino court info
if ($CourtCounty == "San Bernardino") {
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO alkouric_darling.customer(CaseNumber, CourtCounty, CourtStreetAddress, CourtMailingAddress, CourtCity, CourtZip, CourtBranchName)
          VALUES ('$CaseNumber', 'San Bernardino', '351 N. Arrowhead Ave', '351 N. Arrowhead Ave', 'San Bernardino', '92415-0245', 'Family Law')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

// enter Los Angeles court info
if ($CourtCounty == "Los Angeles") {
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO alkouric_darling.customer(CaseNumber, CourtCounty, CourtStreetAddress, CourtMailingAddress, CourtCity, CourtZip, CourtBranchName)
          VALUES ('$CaseNumber','Los Angeles', '351 N. Arrowhead Ave', '351 N. Arrowhead Ave', 'San Bernardino', '92415-0245', 'Family Law')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
}

// enter Orange court info
if ($CourtCounty == "Orange") {
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO alkouric_darling.customer(CaseNumber, CourtCounty, CourtStreetAddress, CourtMailingAddress, CourtCity, CourtZip, CourtBranchName)
          VALUES ('$CaseNumber','Orange', '341 The City Drive', '341 The City Drive ', 'Orange', '92868-3209 ', 'Family Law')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

// enter Respondent / Petitioner Information
if ($RespondentOrPetitioner == "p") {
    echo "<b>Respondent/Petitioner Info</b><br>";
    echo "Petitioner (you):  ".$PetitionerFirstName." ".$PetitionerLastName;
    echo "<br>Attorney(yours): ".$AttorneyFullName;
    echo "<br>Respondent: ".$RespondentFirstName." ".$RespondentLastName;
    echo "<br>Attorney (theirs): ".$RespondentAttorneyFullName;
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO alkouric_darling.customer(CaseNumber, PetitionerFirstName, PetitionerLastName, RespondentFirstName, RespondentLastName, RespondentAttorneyFullName, PetitionerAttorneyFullName )
          VALUES ('$CaseNumber','$PetitionerFirstName', '$PetitionerLastName', '$RespondentFirstName', '$RespondentLastName','$RespondentAttorneyFullName','$AttorneyFullName')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

// enter Respondent / Petitioner Information
if ($RespondentOrPetitioner == "r") {
    echo "<b>Respondent/Petitioner Info</b><br>";
    echo "Petitioner:  ".$PetitionerFirstName." ".$PetitionerLastName;
    echo "<br>Attorney (theirs): ".$PetitionerAttorneyFullName;
    echo "<br>Respondent(you): ".$RespondentFirstName." ".$RespondentLastName;
    echo "<br>Attorney(yours): ".$AttorneyFullName;
    $sql = "REPLACE INTO alkouric_darling.customer(CaseNumber, RespondentFirstName, RespondentLastName, PetitionerFirstName, PetitionerLastName, RespondentAttorneyFullName, PetitionerAttorneyFullName )
          VALUES ('$CaseNumber','$RespondentFirstName', '$RespondentLastName', '$PetitionerFirstName', '$PetitionerLastName','$AttorneyFullName', '$PetitionerAttorneyFullName')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
}

// Insert Values into Database
$sql = "REPLACE INTO alkouric_darling.customer(CaseNumber, FirstName, LastName, AddressLine1 , AddressLine2, City , State , Zip , County, RespondentOrPetitioner, PhoneCell , PhoneHome , PhoneWork , Email , DOB, DriversLicense, Social, OtherPartyFirstName, OtherPartyLastName, OtherPartyEmail, OtherPartyAddressLine1, OtherPartyPhoneHome, OtherPartyPhoneCell, OtherPartyPhoneWork , OtherPartyDOB , OtherPartyDriversLicense , OtherPartySocial , AttorneyFullName , AttorneyFullAddress , AttorneyFirmName, AttorneyBar, AttorneyPhone , AttorneyEmail, OtherPartyAddressLine2, OtherPartyCity , Child1FirstName, Child1LastName, Child1DOB, Child1Gender, Child1AddressLine1, Child1AddressLine2, Child1City, Child1State, Child1Zip, Child1PersonLivedWith, Child1PersonLivedWithFullAddress, Child1PeriodOfResidenceFrom, Child2FirstName, Child2LastName, Child2DOB, Child2Gender, Child2AddressLine1, Child2AddressLine2, Child2City, Child2State, Child2Zip, Child2PersonLivedWith, Child2PersonLivedWithFullAddress, Child2PeriodOfResidenceFrom, OtherPartyAttorneyFullName, OtherPartyZip, OtherPartyState)
          VALUES ('$CaseNumber', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$AddressLine1 ', '$AddressLine2', '$City ', '$State ', '$Zip ', '$County', '$RespondentOrPetitioner', '$PhoneCell ', '$PhoneHome ', '$PhoneWork ', '$Email ', '$DOB', '$DriversLicense', '$Social', '$OtherPartyFirstName', '$OtherPartyLastName', '$OtherPartyEmail', '$OtherPartyAddressLine1', '$OtherPartyPhoneHome', '$OtherPartyPhoneCell', '$OtherPartyPhoneWork ', '$OtherPartyDOB ', '$OtherPartyDriversLicense ', '$OtherPartySocial ', '$AttorneyFullName ', '$AttorneyFullAddress ', '$AttorneyFirmName', '$AttorneyBar', '$AttorneyPhone ', '$AttorneyEmail ', '$OtherPartyAddressLine2', '$OtherPartyCity', '$Child1FirstName', '$Child1LastName', '$Child1DOB', '$Child1Gender', '$Child1AddressLine1', '$Child1AddressLine2', '$Child1City', '$Child1State', '$Child1Zip', '$Child1PersonLivedWith', '$Child1PersonLivedWithFullAddress', '$Child1PeriodOfResidenceFrom', '$Child2FirstName', '$Child2LastName', '$Child2DOB', '$Child2Gender', '$Child2AddressLine1', '$Child2AddressLine2', '$Child2City', '$Child2State', '$Child2Zip', '$Child2PersonLivedWith', '$Child2PersonLivedWithFullAddress', '$Child2PeriodOfResidenceFrom','$OtherPartyAttorneyFullName','$OtherPartyZip','$OtherPartyState')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: have you tried to use UPDATE instead of REPLACE with WHERE Condition?

Comment: No, but should it matter?  My replace into is working just fine on other pages and was working great up until now.

Comment: try to run the SQL query directly into phpmyadmin or any other mysql interface to be sure nothing wrong with your query. use echo $sql in your php page to get the end sql query and run it in sql interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to WPCODER pointing me in the right direction.  Using:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Found this great reference:

[PHP MYSQL UPDATE if Exist or INSERT if not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853190/php-mysql-update-if-exist-or-insert-if-not)