# In PHP most efficient way to update a database row if it already exist or to create one if it doesn't exist

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

I have a client server application. On the server I have this PHP api.
I need this api to check if a row with a specific set of values exist.
If it exist it must update its quantity (current quantity + the quantity sent by the client).
If it doesn't exist it must create a new row with that specific set of values and the quantity sent by the client.

My question is: is there a better and more efficient way to achieve this without doing 2 query?
Thanks in advance

This is my code snippet:

```
$checkExistingItemQuery = $i_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `inventory` WHERE `user`=? AND `location`=? AND `item`=? AND `weight`=? AND `comment`=?");     
            $checkExistingItemQuery->bind_param("iiiii", $userId, $locationId, $itemId, $itemWeight, $commentId);
            
$checkExistingItemQuery->execute();

$resultExistingItemQuery = $checkExistingItemQuery->fetch();

if($resultExistingItemQuery === false) {//a row with the same infos doesn't exist
   $updateItemQuery = $i_conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `inventory`(`user`, `location`, `item`, `quantity`, `weight`, `comment`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");     
   $updateItemQuery->bind_param("iiiiii", $userId, $locationId, $itemId, $itemQuantity, $itemWeight, $commentId);
                
   $updateItemQuery->execute();
                
   $updateItemQuery->bind_result($result);

} else {        
   $existingItemId = $resultExistingItemQuery.['id'];

   $insertItemQuery = $i_conn->prepare("UPDATE `inventory` SET `quantity` = `quantity` + ? WHERE `id` = ?");     
   $insertItemQuery->bind_param("ii", $itemQuantity, $existingItemId);
                
   $insertItemQuery->execute();
                
   $insertItemQuery->bind_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: Have a look through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853190/php-mysql-update-if-exist-or-insert-if-not.